# Trouble use library(agricolae)

Tags: r

I just updated the R version from 4.0.4 to 4.1.3.

I have successfully installed
`install.packages("agricolae")`.

But, when I run the syntax
`library(agricolae)`,

The output in RGUI shown:

`Warning message: package ‘agricolae’ was built under R version 4.0.5`.

Then, the output in RStudio shown:

`Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘agricolae’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘magrittr’`.

So, I tried to install the packages of "magrittr", but failed. The output in RStudio shown:

`The system cannot find the path specified. make: \*\*\* \[pipe.o\] Error 1 ERROR: compilation failed for package 'magrittr'`

`* removing 'C:/Users/Anna/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/magrittr' Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘magrittr’ had non-zero exit status\`.

How can I install the package of agricolae?

Comment: If you just updated your R version, have you tried restarting your session ?

Comment: @Basti Thank you! I've just tried restarting my session and the problem solved.